# Proving $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^{3}-y^{3}}{x^{2}+y^2}=0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

Let's say I wish to find the limit of $\frac{x^{3}-y^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$. It is very simple to just let $y=mx;m\in\mathbb{R}$, and speculate that since the expression comes out to be $0$ on taking the limit and not a function of $m$, the limit may be $0$. Although, this obviously isn't very rigorous, because we're missing on infinitely many other paths of approach. So how would we prove this limit using Epsilon-delta. Any hints or ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hint. Note that $\frac{x^{3}-y^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=x\cdot\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}-y\cdot\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition to verify that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2} = 0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3008068/use-the-epsilon-delta-definition-to-verify-that-lim-x-y-to0-0-frac)

Comment: $|x|^3/(x^2+y^2)\le |x|.$ Another way for these type of problems is to use polar coordinates. The denominator becomes $r^2.$